# What does MinimumLevel and Override mean in appsettings.json logging context?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, .net-core

I am looking at the appsettings.json from [Serilog sample project](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-docker/blob/master/web-sample/src/appsettings.json), which has the following snippet:

```
"MinimumLevel": {
  "Default": "Debug",
  "Override": {
    "System": "Information",
    "Microsoft": "Information"
  }
}
```

In this context, what is the purpose of `Override`?  The `System` and `Microsoft` entries don't have a parent setting in the `MinimumLevel` node, so what is it overriding?

Unless I am completely misunderstanding the purpose of `Override`.

Answer (score 5):

By default, you're saying any log entry that is severity "Debug" or higher should be sent to your sink(s) (console, file, etc).

This is similar behavior to [Microsoft's document on logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#configuration):

> For example, logging configuration is commonly provided by the `Logging` section of app settings files. The following example shows the contents of a typical appsettings.Development.json file:
>
> ```
> {
>   "Logging": {
>     "LogLevel": {
>       "Default": "Debug",
>       "System": "Information",
>       "Microsoft": "Information"
>     },
>     "Console": {
>       "IncludeScopes": true
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> The `LogLevel` property under `Logging` specifies the minimum level to log for selected categories. In the example, `System` and `Microsoft` categories log at `Information` level, and all others log at `Debug` level.

The override section is for changing that minimum log level for types of a given namespace. In your example that means that a log from a `System.*` or `Microsoft.*` namespace must be Information or higher to be shown.

Normally you'd want to see `Debug` log entries for *your code*, but a higher level (like `Information` or `Warning`) for "not your code", like Microsoft and System.

Instead of putting this configuration in a configuation file you could also use code:

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .UseSerilog((ctx, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.ReadFrom.Configuration(ctx.Configuration)
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information);
    })
    .Build();
```

<sub>[Code from kimsereyblog.blogspot.com](https://kimsereyblog.blogspot.com/2018/02/logging-in-asp-net-core-with-serilog.html)</sub>

Their explanation for the process is:

> From the example we saw that we can configure a default minimum level of logging `.MinimumLevel.Debug()`. We can also override that default for certain namespaces, for example here we set the minimum level of logging for `Microsoft` namespace to `Information`. This will prevent ASP.NET Core to log all debug logs while keeping our own debug logs.

Another explanation, from [nblumhardt.com](https://nblumhardt.com/2016/07/serilog-2-minimumlevel-override/):

> The first argument of `Override` is a source context prefix, which is normally matched against the namespace-qualified type name of the class associated with the logger.
>
> ...
>
> The effect of the configuration above, then, is to generate events only at or above the `Warning` level when the logger is owned by a type in a `Microsoft.*` namespace.

Comment: The most important part of OP's question is `override`.  Your answer didn't discuss it instead it referenced a couple of blog posts that make the topic clear as mud.

Comment: Hopefully I've made the mud more clear.