# Serilog - MinimumLevel Override required to make the default effective

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog

I read here [What does MinimumLevel and Override mean in appsettings.json logging context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54990647/what-does-minimumlevel-and-override-mean-in-appsettings-json-logging-context) that `Default` means *default* in Serilog - therefore, the following configuration should work:

**appSettings.json**

```json
"Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
    }
}
```

However, with the config above I still get `Information` level logs like this:

```
[11:53:56 INF] Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:5000
[11:53:56 INF] Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
[11:53:56 INF] Hosting environment: Development
[11:53:56 INF] Content root path: [some_path]
```

Only effective configuration for me is:

```json
"Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning",
        "Override": {
            "Microsoft": "Warning",
            "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Warning"
        }
    }
}
```

With the above, no `Information` -level logs are displayed. It seems contradictory to the mentioned stackoverflow answer and common sense.

This is how I do setup the logger:

```java
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                 .ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb)
                 .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
                 .WriteTo.Console(theme: AnsiConsoleTheme.Code)
                 .CreateLogger();
```

The project is developed with .NET Core 3.1.

I would like to know whether there is something peculiar with serilog or I am missing some important step in configuration?

For the sake of completness - here is `Main`:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Log.Fatal(exception, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
    }
    finally
    {
        Log.CloseAndFlush();
    }
}
```

and `CreateHostBuilder`:

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseSerilog()
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

The Serilog is initialized with the code mentioned above (`Log.Logger = ...`) in the very first line of `ConfigureServices` in `Startup.cs`.

Comment: Can you share the code where you add Serilog to the ASP.Net Core?

Comment: @Kahbazi the question is extended with the code now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours of searches and tries I have noticed that there is no single source that would recommend to initialize Serilog inside any of `Startup.cs` methods.

The solution for me is to move the initialization to the `Program.cs` in the following way:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SetupSerilog();
    try
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Log.Fatal(exception, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
    }
    finally
    {
        Log.CloseAndFlush();
    }
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseSerilog()
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });

private static void SetupSerilog()
{
    var appsettingsFilename = "appsettings.json";

    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile(appsettingsFilename)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();

    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb)
        .WriteTo.Console(theme: AnsiConsoleTheme.Code)
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
        .CreateLogger();
}
```

Unfortunately, I barely understand why is so and what is the reason that `Serilog` behaves differently, depending on whether the logger is defined inside the constructor, `ConfigureServices` or `Configure` of `Startup.cs`. My very initial idea was to have an easy access to the `IConfiguration`. Nevertheless, maybe someone will find this cue above usefull.

Comment: It's better to set up your logging as early as possible (so, in Program.cs), so you can capture startup failures. See [this blog entry](https://nblumhardt.com/2019/10/serilog-in-aspnetcore-3/#logger-initialization-in-programcs) from Nicholas Blumhardt (Serilog creator).